# Gradient of a scalar function: path taken by a particle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

Just the last part, I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=4x^3-12xy^2-4x$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=4y^3-12x^2y+4y$$

For the steepest descent, we should have (implicit derivative gives us slope, we find -1/that to find the perpendicular to the slope):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\bigg(-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}\bigg)^{-1}$$

$$dy(x^3-3xy^2-x)+dx(-y^3+3x^2y-y)=0$$

This is an exact differential equation. Solution gives

$$xy(x^2-y^2-1)=C$$

Comment: Hmm there was nothing like this in my course notes. Thanks for your help though!